# Finding an explicit formula for this recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the recurrence relation $a_{n}=2a_{n-1}^{2}-1$ with the initial term $a_{0}=3$. The first few terms in this sequence are $3,17,577,665857,\dots$

Does anyone know how to find an explicit formula for this relation?

Comment: If $a=\cosh t$ then $2a^2-1=\cosh2t$ etc.

Comment: One thing I see is that $3=2+1,17=2^4+1$, and we have $$2(2^k+1)^2-1=2^{2k+1}+2^{k+2}+1$$ but this doesn't immediately lend itself to a nice formula...

Comment: Lord Shark of the Unknown's comment above is the key to solving this. Set $a_n = \cosh t_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n = \frac{1}{2}((1 + \sqrt2)^{2^n} + (1 - \sqrt2)^{2^n})$

Comment: The question asks: "Does anyone know **how** to find an explicit formula for this relation?"

Comment: you can find an explicit formula by looking the sequence up in the OEIS

Comment: This is correct, but I really am interested how you got this.